# Слайдер в телеграм боте на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет!
Как сделать подобный слайдер в **телеграм боте** на *pyTelegrambotapi*?

(если это принципиально, могу пересесть на другую библиотеку)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри на гитхабе пример с инлайн клавиатурой https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py

1. Создаёшь сообщение, добавляя к ней инлайн клавиатуру
2. Обрабатываешь callback, смотришь на номер на клавиатуре в callback и используешь метод edit message (меняешь картинку и номер на клавиатуре)